# Why is my hard drive "performing way below expectations"?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I recently ran a full-system diagnostic using [UserBenchmark.com](http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/)'s diagnostic program. Once run, it showed the following results for my drive:

[image]

The Kingston is about 8 years old now, so I'm not expecting the greatest speeds for it, but the Barracuda is virtually brand new. It's a SATA III connected to SATA II motherboard headers, so I'm also not expecting SATA III speeds, but even SATA II maxes out at 3Gb/s (375 MB/s), so why am I getting so much lower than that, *and* so much lower than other owners of the same drive?

Below are CrystalDiskMark results for the drive using different file sizes, each one tested 5 times:

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Update

As requested, here are the desktop's specs:

- **Processor:** Intel Core i3-2100 3.1GHz Dual-Core
- **RAM:** 16GB DDR3
- **Motherboard:** ASRock H61M-HVS
- **Chipset:** Intel H61
- **OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit

Feel free to request any more if you think it'll help.

Comment: Could be any number of things. Without system specifications it is hard to know. Intel had a bug in their SATA chipset years ago that meant performance might degrade over time: https://www.anandtech.com/show/4142/intel-discovers-bug-in-6series-chipset-begins-recall You need to provide more than just benchmarks.

Comment: @Mokubai I've updated to include basic specs. Were there any specific specs that you had in mind?

Comment: Motherboard model and chipset might also be worthwhile.

Comment: Just added. Chipset was taken from the motherboard's manual.

Comment: What exactly about the hard drive is not meeting your expectations?  The sequential read speeds are what I would expect from a hard drive.   If you have problems with your non-sequential read speeds, do a disk defrag.

Comment: Your own screenshot shows 70.9% compared to other drives of the same drive; why is this a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that that drive IS performing to expectations.

Just because the SATA port can handle 300 megs per second, that does not mean the hard drive can - 100 megabytes is about par for a hard drive - even on SATA3 interface.

The comment about the drive performing way below expectations must be a software fault, because the actual data shows its performing to spec, and overall "Very Good" result.   That drives in newer, faster systems can perform sligthly better then your 6 year old (based on CPU model) chipset is not a surprise.

Also, there are different exact models of this drive, which will perform slightly better or worse, depending on age, firmware, factory etc.

Comment: Thanks for putting my mind at ease. As mentioned in my answer, I'm aware that the SATA limit is a theoretical maximum throughput, my worry was the "way below expectations" warning, but it does make sense to me that this is just a case of the law of averages - that there are instances of the same drive that will perform better than it just as there are those that will perform worse. Thanks again.